# What verb best describes "causing another block to become stale"?

Tags: doublespend, terminology, chain-reorganization, selfish-mining, block-withholding

For example, suppose I'm selfish mining; you publish a block and then I immediately publish two, what did I do to your block?
Similarly, if I'm executing a double-spend attack, my goal is to ?___? the block containing the transaction standing in the way of my double-spend.
I'm looking for a transitive verb that also works well in passive tense.

Comment: I think my favorite I've come across so far is "supplant". FWIW I'm writing up some lecture notes; there's objections to the verb "orphan" which I had been using, so I'm looking for a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a well-established term, yet. My spontaneous preference would be to use *"to displace"* or *"to supersede"* a block—there is only one spot in the best chain at each height and the new block took it from the old block.

In the past I have also described it as "reorganizing out" a block.

Answer (score 1):

"To override" seems fine.